# Laravel - Method [orderBy] does not exist on Axois Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, eloquent

I'm trying to get some records from my DB and I'm getting `Method [orderBy] does not exist` I'm making this request with Axois.

Route

```
Route::get('/get-order-statuses', 'Backend\Orders\OrderStatuses@index');
```

Controller Code

```
public function index()
    {
        $statuses = OrderStatuses::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get(['id', 'status', 'status_description']);

        return response()
            ->json([
                'statuses' => $statuses
            ]);
    }
```

Model Code

```
protected $table = 'order_statuses';
    protected $fillable = [
        'statues', 'status_description', 'userId',
    ];
```

Vue template

```
import { get } from '../../helpers/api'
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    isLoading: true,
                    loaded: false,
                    statuses: []
                }
            },
            created() {
                get('get-order-statuses')
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(res);
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        this.loaded = true;
                    })
            }
```

Comment: So rewrite your query, open query builder manual and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orderBy` is a method of `QueryBuilder`, so before using it, you should get instance of `QueryBuilder`.

Also `get` does not take fields as it's argument.

Considering abovementioned your query can be rewritten as:

```
$statuses = OrderStatuses::select('id', 'status', 'status_description')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Or:

```
$statuses = DB::table('order_statuses')
    ->select('id', 'status', 'status_description')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Also

```
$statuses = OrderStatuses::all()
    ->select('id', 'status', 'status_description')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: That's strange, are you sure you eloquent model is named as `OrderStatuses`? Also try my second variant of query.

Comment: Also added third variant. Maybe I'm mistaken and `::select` is used in laravel4 and removed in laravel5.

Comment: the third variant also returns Method [all] does not exist

Comment: could it be because both the controller and the model have the same class name?

Comment: I suppose it could be. You can name your controllers with `Controller` suffix so as to improve readability.

Comment: @Yosef I think you are right, make your controller name `OrderStatusesController` and see what happens, you should follow the laravel official docs

Comment: I usually name my Controllers with the Controller suffix i guess i forgot this time

Comment: Yup it was that I changed it to `OrderStatusesController ` and all the other methods worked :)

Comment: Thanks everyone :)